# CDN Tax Receipts - do not issue

Tags: cdn-tax-receipts

I'm trying to figure out the logic for issuing a tax receipt.  Can someone tell me - if the contact record has no address and no email, will the system still generate a tax receipt?

Also - there are times when I need to not issue a receipt for a financial type that normally does get a receipt.  for example a 3rd party fundraiser that I would put in our "general donation" financial type, is there a way to mark this single contribution to not issue a tax receipts?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a PDF receipt will still be generated even if there is no address.

Yes, you can set the non-deductible amount to the full amount of the donation under Additional Details and then no tax receipt will be issued. Alternatively, if this happens a lot, it might be simpler to set up a separate  financial type for Non-deductible general donations, which is a little less error prone.

Comment: thanks for your help!